# Script needed to alert when the sessions are about to get filled

Tags: oracle10g

We have an oracle 10g database with sessions=300. I need help in writing a script which can alert me when the sessions have reached 290.

`SQL> select name,value from v$spparameter where name='sessions';`

```
NAME      VALUE
-------- ------------
sessions 300
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for the query to get the number of sessions?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM v$session
```

If that exceeds 290 you could send an email (either via the [UTL_MAIL package](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10802/u_mail.htm) or some other API for sending mail).  This could be scheduled using [DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm) or [DBMS_JOB](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_job.htm) or via your favorite external scheduler like cron.  Or, potentially, you could run the check from a logon trigger in the database.